# Show 404 error on accessing specific folder structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am displaying 404 error message if the user tries to access a specific folder struture

like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protected$
RewriteRule .* /404.cfm [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protected/pdf$
RewriteRule .* /404.cfm [NC,L]
```

Is there any way to combine both

```
/protected/pdf and /protected
```

in one condition and a forward slash at the end as optional

I tried this to make last forward slash optional, like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protected/?$
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(protected|protected/pdf)/?$
RewriteRule .* /404.cfm [NC,L]
```

You can also  use conditions with OR flag

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protected/?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protected/pdf/?$
RewriteRule .* /404.cfm [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It do not match:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protected/?$
```

mean match everything that start with /protected with an optional / and end.
I you want to match it you have to remove the $.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protected/?.*$
```

or :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protected
```

Or you can stay restrictive as @starkeen offers solution, it depend on your needs.